# List Woocommerce product with its category ID - MySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using a MySQL query to list all product addon variations(swatches), I am able to do this fine, as well as list the product the variation is associated with. The problem I have is listing that products category id as well.

I have no formal training in MySQL so any help and advise on performance etc. will also be of great value!

Here is the code I am using to get the list of addon variations and their products, just need to get the category ID's for those products as well.

```
$prod_attributes_sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT wt.slug AS term_slug, wtr.term_taxonomy_id, wpp.post_title AS wpost_title, wt.term_id AS wpt_terms, cpt.term_id AS cpt_terms
    FROM '
. " {$wc_price_table->cat_price_table_name} cpt"
. ' RIGHT OUTER JOIN wp_terms wt ON cpt.term_id=wt.term_id'
. ' INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wtr ON wt.term_id = wtr.term_taxonomy_id'
. ' INNER JOIN wp_posts wpp ON wtr.object_id = wpp.ID'
. ' RIGHT OUTER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ttx on wt.term_id = ttx.term_id'
. ' WHERE ttx.taxonomy IN (\'' . implode("','", $slugsnews) . '\')'
. ' ORDER BY wt.name';
$prod_attributes = $wpdb->get_results($prod_attributes_sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Which outputs the list of addon variations and the product they are associated to. But how would I go about including the category id of those products.

Let me know if I need to add any further explanation or code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to change the query to include the `$term_id`, using the following `foreach` to get the terms:

```
        $term_id = array();
        foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
            foreach ($category['terms'] as $term) {
                $term_id[] = $term->term_id;
            }
        }
```

and and included in my sql like this:

```
        $prod_attributes_sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT wt.slug AS term_slug, wt.name, ttx.taxonomy, wtr.term_taxonomy_id, wpp.post_title AS wpost_title, wt.term_id AS wpt_terms, cpt.term_id AS cpt_terms
            FROM '
        . " {$wc_price_table->cat_price_table_name} cpt"
        . ' RIGHT OUTER JOIN wp_terms wt ON cpt.term_id=wt.term_id'
        . ' INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wtr ON wt.term_id = wtr.term_taxonomy_id'
        . ' INNER JOIN wp_posts wpp ON wtr.object_id = wpp.ID'
        . ' RIGHT OUTER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ttx on wt.term_id = ttx.term_id'
        . ' WHERE cpt.term_id IN(' . implode(',', $term_id) . ')'
        . ' OR ttx.taxonomy IN (\'' . implode("','", $slugsnews) . '\')'
        . ' OR ttx.term_taxonomy_id = cpt.term_id'
        . ' ORDER BY wpp.post_title';
        $prod_attributes = $wpdb->get_results($prod_attributes_sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

This works.